# При запуске kohana на сервер, дает ошибку The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: kohana

На локалке все нормально работает.
Kohana::$environment = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT; сменил на 
Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;
Дает такую ошибку:
[image]

Как исправить, может я что то забыл поменять(

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, с дефолтным роутом что-то не так

Comment: он у меня написан так: 



   
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
 ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'page',
  'action'     => 'index',
 )); 

как еще по другому писать?

Comment: дело не в "по-другому". У вас есть указанные контроллер и экшн?

Comment: конечно есть, думаете контроллеры с экшынами виноваты?:)

Comment: проверяйте, чтобы классы с нужным названием были и лежали в нужных местах